# VB.net XMLNodeList returns 0 when using document.selectNodes(XPath)

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have an XML doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.ABCdefg.com/XYZ"
                 xmlns:doc="http://www.ABCdefg.com/LMN"
                 xmlns:history="http://www.ABCdefg.com/LMNHistory">
    
    <import href="ENTypes.xml"/>
    <import href="ENSTR.xml"/>
    <import href="ENNUM.xml"/>
    <types>
        <!--Operations definitions  -->
            <type javaPrefix="Seg" name="James" javaPackage="com.ABCdefg.jk.ox">
                <documentation>
                 A collection of entity creation requests
                </documentation>
                <member name="apiHeader" type="ApiHeaderType" use="optional">
                    <doc:required  r="" c="" u="" />
                    <documentation>
                    Operation header.
                    </documentation>
                </member>
                <member name="EN" type="ENTypes" collection="true">
                    <doc:required  r="" c="" u="" />
                    <documentation>
                       A collection of entities.
                    </documentation>
                </member>
            </type>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

I am trying to get the list of Types in the XML document above. I am using .SelectNodes to get the nodes. See the following code:

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument() 
doc.load("XmlPath")
Dim NodeList As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("definitions/types/*)
```

The NodeList variable has a count of 0. For other xml files, this code worked, but it is not working for this set of xml files

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo here.
Instead of

```xml
definitions/Types/*
```

it should be

```xml
definitions/types/*
```

the later expression works.
You can validate that [here](http://xpather.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I corrected it but still doesn't work

Comment: What exactly not working? What is your output now? Error?

Comment: Dim NodeList As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("definitions/types/*)

Here the variable NodeList  returns the count as 0, expectation is to get 1 XmlNode as there is 1 child node <type></type>

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using Xml Linq

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Module Program
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim ns As XNamespace = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()

        Dim results = doc.Descendants(ns + "type") _
           .Select(Function(x) New With {
                    .Type = CType(x.Attribute("javaPrefix"), String),
                    .name = CType(x.Attribute("name"), String),
                    .package = CType(x.Attribute("javaPackage"), String)
                }).ToList()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
How do i convert results into XML Nodes?
I want to traverse through the entire xml document. 
Get all imports and types inside definitions,  type inside types, all members inside type, and so on

Comment: XML linq is the newer library in Net/Core for doing xml parsing.  The code posted gets every "type" node in the xml file.  You would need a second query to get the IMPORTS values.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer for my question
Since I have got name spaces in the xml file, passing the name space in the SelectNode function and adding namespace in the XPath does the work

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument() 
doc.load("XmlPath")
Dim nameSpace As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nameSpace.AddNamespace("nameSpace1", "www.ABCdefg.com/XYZ")
Dim NodeList As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/nameSpace1:definitions/nameSpace1:types/nameSpace1:*", nameSpace)
```